# Substitute fully instantiated classes with partially instantiated ancestor classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, instantiation, sfinae

I want `accepted_dense_vector<??>::value` to return `'true'` when I give template parameters in the form:

`C<T>` when `C` is `uvector`, `dynamic_array` and `T` is `std::is_arithmetic`.

`std::array<T,S>` when `T` is `std::is_arithmetic`.

`container_reference<C>` when `accepted_dense_vector<C>::value` is 'true'.

All works fine, but in derived, fully instantiated classes A, C, D, I want to remove the workaround `parent` definition.

How can I do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

// Definition of used types.
template<typename T> struct dynamic_array {};
template<typename T> struct uvector {};
struct A : public uvector<double> { typedef uvector<double> parent; };
struct C : public A { typedef A parent; };
struct D : public std::array<double,5> { typedef std::array<double,5> parent; };
template<typename T> struct B : public uvector<T> { typedef uvector<T> parent; };
template<typename T> struct container_reference {};

// Catches 'false', A, C, D  ======== HERE IT IS !!! ========
template<typename C> struct accepted_dense_vector
{
    template<typename C1 = C>
    static typename std::enable_if<accepted_dense_vector<typename C1::parent>::value, std::true_type>::type helper(const C&);
    static std::false_type helper(...);

    constexpr static bool value = decltype(helper(std::declval<C>()))::value;
};
// Catches C<T>
template<template<typename> class C, typename T>
struct accepted_dense_vector<C<T>>
{
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value &&
        (std::is_base_of<uvector<T>, C<T>>::value || std::is_base_of<dynamic_array<T>, C<T>>::value);
};
// Catches std::array<T,S>
template<typename T, size_t S>
struct accepted_dense_vector<std::array<T,S>>
    { constexpr static bool value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value; };

// Catches container_reference<C>
template<typename C>
struct accepted_dense_vector<container_reference<C>>
    { constexpr static bool value = accepted_dense_vector<C>::value; };

int main()
{ // Tests!
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<std::array<double, 5>>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<uvector<double>>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<A>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<D>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<B<int>>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<container_reference<uvector<double>>>::value << endl;
    cout << accepted_dense_vector<int>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go further with your solution. First, you do not need `std::enable_if`. The code will be more readable. Then, instead of using `std::true_type`, use a custom struct that will call `accepted_dense_vector`:

```
template<typename T>
struct forwarder
{
    constexpr static bool value = accepted_dense_vector<T>::value;
};

template<typename T>
static forwarder<uvector<T>> inherit_uvector(uvector<T>*);

static std::false_type inherit_uvector(...);
```

Then, to know whether the type satisfy `accepted...` by inheritance of `uvector<T>`, just use the following line:

```
constexpr static bool is_uvector = decltype(inherit_uvector(new C()))::value;
// C is the template parameter of accepted_dense_vector
```

How does this works ?

- if `C` inherits `uvector<T>`, the first static function is choosed, and decltype will return `forwarder<uvector<T>>`. Then, 'calling' `::value` on it will call `accepted...`.
- else, if `C` does not inherits `uvector<T>`, the second function is choosed, and decltype will return `std::false_type`.

The same trick can be used with the other inheritances. Also, `B<T>` was catched with the second specialization of `accepted...`. Thus, the `::parent` typedef is not needed anymore.

Here is the full code ([live here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3maWAb%240)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Definition of used types.
template<typename T> struct uvector {};
template<typename T> struct dynamic_array {};
template<typename T> struct container_reference {};

struct A : public uvector<double> {};
template<typename T> struct B : public uvector<T> {};
struct C : public A {};
struct D : public std::array<double,5> {};
struct E : public uvector<string> {};
struct F : public std::array<string,16> {};

// Catches 'false', A, C, D  ======== HERE IT IS !!! ========
template<typename C>
struct accepted_dense_vector
{
   template<typename T>
   struct forwarder
   {
      constexpr static bool value = accepted_dense_vector<T>::value;
   };

   // uvector
   template<typename T>
   static forwarder<uvector<T>> inherit_uvector(uvector<T>*);
   static std::false_type inherit_uvector(...);

   // std::array
   template<typename T, size_t S>
   static forwarder<std::array<T,S>> inherit_stdarray(std::array<T,S>*);
   static std::false_type inherit_stdarray(...);

   // same for dynamic_array<T>

    constexpr static bool is_uvector = decltype(inherit_uvector(new C()))::value;
    constexpr static bool is_stdarray = decltype(inherit_stdarray(new C()))::value;
    constexpr static bool value = is_uvector || is_stdarray;
};


// Catches C<T>
// /!\ Also catches anything which is template<typename> class (for example, B)
// => B::parent is not needed, because of the use of std::is_base_of
template<template<typename> class C, typename T>
struct accepted_dense_vector<C<T>>
{
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value &&
        (std::is_base_of<uvector<T>, C<T>>::value || std::is_base_of<dynamic_array<T>, C<T>>::value);
};

// Catches std::array<T,S>
template<typename T, size_t S>
struct accepted_dense_vector<std::array<T,S>>
{
   constexpr static bool value = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value;
};

// Catches container_reference<C>
template<typename C>
struct accepted_dense_vector<container_reference<C>>
{
   constexpr static bool value = accepted_dense_vector<C>::value;
};

int main()
{ // Tests!
    cout << "array = " << accepted_dense_vector<std::array<double, 5>>::value << endl;
    cout << "uvector = " << accepted_dense_vector<uvector<double>>::value << endl;
    cout << "ref = " << accepted_dense_vector<container_reference<uvector<double>>>::value << endl;
    cout << "A = " << accepted_dense_vector<A>::value << endl;
    cout << "B = " << accepted_dense_vector<B<int>>::value << endl;
    cout << "C = " << accepted_dense_vector<C>::value << endl;
    cout << "D = " << accepted_dense_vector<D>::value << endl;
    cout << "E = " << accepted_dense_vector<E>::value << endl;
    cout << "F = " << accepted_dense_vector<F>::value << endl;
    cout << "int = " << accepted_dense_vector<int>::value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```